# Deleting items below a given average in SQLite: I get a syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a very large table.

Each row has a uniqueId and an itemId. I want to delete all items that are priced below a given average. I figured something like this should work, but it doesnt:

```
 DELETE FROM items GROUP BY itemId HAVING avg(price) < ?
```

SQLite complains:

> near "GROUP": syntax error

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM items as i1 
WHERE i1.itemID in (
    Select i2.itemID 
    FROM items as i2
    GROUP BY i2.itemId 
    HAVING avg(price) < "user defined threshold" )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
delete I 
from   items I join
       (select itemId,avg(price) as price
       from items
       GROUP BY itemId)a
on     I.itemId=a.itemId
where  I.price<a.price
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be something like this

```
DELETE FROM items WHERE itemId HAVING avg(price) < ?
```